# Initialize members of class inside array while declaration

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

How can i initialize MyClass members while declaration of array?

```
class MyClass {
   int var1;
   String[] var2;
}

MyClass[] c = new MyClass[] {...};
```

How to properly write in {...}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a constructor:

```
class MyClass {
   int var1;
   String[] var2;
   public MyClass(int v1, String[] v2){
       var1=v1;
       var2=v2;
   }
}
```

and then do as follows:

```
MyClass[] c =new MyClass[]{new MyClass(16, new String[]{"a", "b"}), new MyClass(26, new String[]{"c", "d"});
```

Call the constructor multiple times inside the array declarator.

Comment: Although, solution is valid, i would like to avoid constructor as handicapping element.

Comment: You are missing the reference to `MyClass[]`.

Comment: @vikram My bad, sorry about the typo. Saar: No, you need to do this. The JLS defines array initializers to take objects, and objects need to be made by either factories or constructors.